# Blue spec compiler issue

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, vmware

I am trying to download blue spec compiler and I have tried these following steps-

```
sudo apt install ghc libghc-regex-compat-dev libghc-syb-dev iverilog
sudo apt install libghc-old-time-dev libfontconfig1-dev libx11-dev
sudo apt install libghc-split-dev libxft-dev flex bison libxft-dev
sudo apt install tcl-dev tk-dev libfontconfig1-dev libx11-dev gperf
sudo apt install itcl3-dev itk3-dev autoconf git

git clone --recursive https://github.com/B-Lang-org/bsc
cd bsc

make all
```

But while running "make all" command it stops showing progress after a particular point .

[image]

I have also tried adding --debug option to get more detailed output , but there wan't much difference shown .

[image]

Can anybody help me with this issue ? How to solve this? I am running Ubuntu(20.04 LTS) on Vmware.

Comment: Is the compiler using CPU? If so, it may just take a bit of time. I see no real issue here.

Comment: but I have actually waited for 12 hours and this is still stuck here ?

Comment: Yes , it is using CPU

Comment: If it's still running but using massive amounts of memory, it may be swapping. This would make it take longer than usual.  If this is the case, and if you're able to allocate more memory to your virtual machine, then do that. Check in `top` how much memory the process is trying to use.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: @Kusalananda i have given 2.4 ram and swapping warning (already given by vmware) is from 2.5 . So, I don't think so if there is a swapping issue . Moreover when I wait for like 12 hours , I find the system extremely slow or sometime freezing . Any idea what should I do

Comment: Sure , I'll take care of it.

Comment: Testing → `bsc` compilation time was ~20 minutes. From 10 to 15 min the RAM use was 3.9 .. 4.1 GB → Test 1: AMD A8-5500B ; Test 2: Intel i5-650. .... ... 1 and 2 almost equal time / RAM use.

Comment: Can you please explain more what are you trying to say ?